# Remove Element from JavaScript array in .NET core Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have input when the user click on add button it should add a new li in the ul list and add a new object in array "Keywords" to send it to the action,
but the problem is when the user removes an element from the ul list I remove the index of the element from the array it didn't work however the removal of the li element works well.
here is the script:

[image]

and this is the HTML:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Karmen, please share the code instead of picture.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
delbtns = $(".delete");
        for (var i = 0; i < delbtns.length; i++) {
            delbtns[i].onclick = function () {
                this.parentNode.remove();
                keywords.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
```

to

```
$(".delete").on('click', function (event) {
            var delbtns = $(".delete");
            for (var i = 0; i < delbtns.length; i++) {
                if (this == delbtns[i]) {
                    this.parentNode.remove();
                    keywords.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        })
```

result:
[image]